# Making the privileges page easier to find

Tags: feature-request

I've found the [privileges](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/privileges) page really useful, to see what features of the site I have (but perhaps aren't using), or as a means of motivation. But unfortunately, I've always seemed to have difficulty finding it; on several occasions, I've tried to remember where it is located without success.

Today spent some time digging around the site to actually find out the easiest route to the page.
The only place I could find a link is under [users -> moderators](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) and clicking on "privileges earned through reputation".

My question is twofold:

- Are there other ways that the privileges page can be accessed, that I've missed? (short of typing "https://electronics.stackexchange.com/privileges" into the browser)
- Could we consider adding a more obvious link, or making the existing links easier to locate?

EDIT:
I see now that it's also located in the box when I hover over my name at the top, which I guess is accessible enough, however I've always clicked on my name, without hovering. Perhaps a privileges link on the profile proper would be more obvious?

Comment: Didn't know about the box, thanks a lot!

Comment: It's a little strange though. The privileges page isn't really part of your account, so I wouldn't think it to be in that box. Can't it get a place in the header, next to review, chat, meta, ...?

Comment: I agree. I also would like a badge progress page

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky There is a limited badge progress box if you go into a review queue and hover over the progress bar in the upper right. A more comprehensive badge progress feature request was declined years ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-pundit-etc-badge-progress/

Comment: Stacey, have you considered asking this on [metase]? It's a good idea, in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

As you've noticed, the quickest way is to hover on your profile name and the link appears.

If you want to suggest a change, probably the best place to look into is meta.stackoverflow, because it's there that changes to the engine are made. This meta is specific to electronics.stackexchange, and doesn't have the same visibility.

Comment: Local SE metas can be used as a place to build up support for an idea before going to the wild jungle of meta.SE.

Answer (score -1):

Click on the help (?) Icon on the top bar, then click "Help center". There is a lot of topics there, and you'll see a link to the privileges page.

Everything is in the help center, but nobody ever think about checking there.